# How to Configure Angular 6 project with Mocha and Karma?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular6, mocha.js

I am having a Angular 6 project and I wanted to configure Mocha with karma inside it.

I have added the required npm or dependencies from mocha but not able to replace Mocha with Jasmine. I think I need to update the karma.conf.js .

Please suggest the configuration or the sample application. Any tutorial link will be useful.